# Calculate probability using combinations

Tags: probability, combinations

There are two red balls, four green balls, two blue balls, and four yellow balls in a basket. The balls are equally likely to be chosen. What is the probability of choosing at least one blue or green ball when choosing four balls?

n(at least one blue ball) = n(any 4 balls) - n(no blue ball) = 12 C 4 - 10 C 4 = 285

p(at least one blue ball) = n(at least one blue ball)/n(any 4 balls) = 285/495 = 0.576

n(at least one green ball) = n(any 4 balls) - n(no green ball) = 12 C 4 - 8 C 4 = 425

p(at least one green ball) = n(at least one blue ball)/n(any 4 balls) = 425/495 = 0.859

Please let me know if my work is incorrect. I think the probability of choosing at least a blue ball or a green ball should not sum up to more than 1. Also, sorry if I am improperly formatting my math. Could you teach me how to format math equations? I still do not understand how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: You correctly calculated the probability of drawing at least one blue.  You correctly calculated the probability of drawing at least one green.  Your concern that their sum is over $1$ is unfounded because adding these together does not correspond to a probability.  You may be incorrectly remembering that $\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)$ when $A$ and $B$ are **disjoint** events, but these are not disjoint.  You can clearly simultaneously draw at least one blue *and* at least one green at the same time.

Comment: As for calculating the probability of drawing at least one blue *or* green... just imagine two piles instead of four piles... the red/yellow pile, and the blue/green pile... and go about it like you would otherwise.  Alternatively, continue like you had but correctly apply inclusion-exclusion... while $\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)$ is true for disjoint events it is not necessarily true otherwise.  What is always true however is that $\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)\color{red}{-\Pr(A\cap B)}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz, thank you so much for your help! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution will be to first find number of ways of selecting $4$ balls such that none of them are green or blue, in other words we select all the $4$ balls from yellow and red balls. As there are $4$ yellow and $2$ red balls, there are $\displaystyle \small {6 \choose 4}$ ways of doing that.

Then, the number of ways to select $4$ balls such that at least one of them is green or blue is given by,

$\displaystyle \small {12 \choose 4} - {6 \choose 4} = 480$

So the desired probability $ = \displaystyle \small \frac{480}{495} = \frac{32}{33}$